# Why is specializing a monadic function with Identity less efficient than writing it manually?

Tags: performance, haskell, monads, higher-order-functions

I have need two higher-order functions, one taking a side-effect free function and the other taking a monadic function as argument:

```
frobM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> b -> m b
frob :: (a -> a) -> b -> b
```

They are very similar, the second function can be expressed using the first:

```
frob f = runIdentity . frobM (return . f)
```

I'd expect this to be equally efficient as writing `frob` “by hand”, as `Identity` is a newtype that should be deleted at compile-time. However, performance still suffers regardless, as is demonstrated by this criterion micro-benchmark:

```
import Criterion.Main (bench, defaultMain, nf)
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity (runIdentity))

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
       [ bench "frob"  $ nf (frob (+23)) 42
       , bench "frob'" $ nf (frob' (+23)) 42
       ]

-- | Generalized function
frobM :: Monad m => (Int -> m Int) -> Int -> m Int
frobM f n = f $ 2^n `mod` 1024

-- | Specialized function based on the general function
frob' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
frob' f = runIdentity . frobM (return . f)

-- | "Hand written" specialized function.
frob :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
frob f n = f $ 2^n `mod` 1024
```

Output:

```
benchmarking frob
time                 676.1 ns   (673.5 ns .. 678.9 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 675.7 ns   (673.3 ns .. 677.3 ns)
std dev              6.600 ns   (5.984 ns .. 7.324 ns)

benchmarking frob'
time                 706.2 ns   (705.0 ns .. 707.9 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 705.7 ns   (704.5 ns .. 707.4 ns)
std dev              4.630 ns   (3.729 ns .. 6.226 ns)
```

What is causing this? Is there a way to make `frob'` as efficient as `frob`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. With `ghc-7.10 -O2`, I get a timing of 116 ns for both `frob` and `frob'`; with `-O` it's 125 ns for each. (You _did_ use optimisation flags, right?)

Comment: Yes, I did. GHC 8.0.2.

Comment: @leftaroundabout since this seems unreproducible on your machine, could you do me a solid and take a look at https://github.com//jgm/pandoc-types/pull/30? It's the actual problem I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: Just to be sure: when you turned on the optimisations, you also used `-fforce-recomp`? Else GHC will not do anything unless the file itself has changed.

Comment: You'll certainly want `frobM f = \n -> ...` and  `frob f = \n -> ...` so that those can be inlined

Comment: @leftaroundabout that did it! thanks a thousand!

Comment: Common, this has happened to me a good couple of times.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sounds like an answer :)